# AppleScript app to copy filenames in folder and put in randomized order into a .txt

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, filenames

I know fairly little about scripting, especially when it comes to Mac. On my work I have a script (Windows .BAT file) which copy every jpg image filename in the folder, randomizing the order and saves it to a .txt where the names are delimited by line break.

I have tried, tried and tried to accomplish this on a Mac which my colleague is using. I have been googling and testing for hours - but no success.

I want a file equivalent to a BAT file, to just run directly from the folder.

I have tried both with a .sh file and an AppleScript saved as app, no real use to show the code since they do not work and have been altered and destroyed by me.
[image of folder with the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHiXI.jpg)

Is there someone who can help med accomplish this? :)

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

I think I just solved it myself! I placed the navigation command in the script as well, and it worked like a charm! Thank you for putting me in the right direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd Desktop/NYHETER
ls *.jpg | sort -R > list.txt
```

Comment: Nice shebang!  The line below that calls `cd` on a relative path, which in this case, lucked out presumably because your non-interactive shell starts in your home directory, to which `Desktop/` is a viable relative.  This might not always be the case, so you're best using absolute paths that won't be affected by whatever the current working directory is.  In this case, the absolute path would be _`~/Desktop/NYHETER`_. Alternatively, as @wch1zpink intimated, hard-coding the path makes each script folder-specific. You can generalise with `cd "$( dirname "$0" )"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a list of JPEGs like this:

```
ls *.jpg
```

You should be able to get a randomised list like this:

```
ls *.jpg | sort -R
```

And you should be able to get a list, randomise it and save to a file like this:

```
ls *.jpg | sort -R > list.txt
```

---

Note that the *"normal"* way would be to use `shuf` but Apple doesn't supply that with **macOS**, so I suggested `sort -R`.

Another option is to install `core-utils` with **homebrew** and use `gshuf`.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I suppose that code is for the .sh file? I tried it but got this response:

ls: *.jpg: No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

Comment: I have just found out that your suggestion works directly in the terminal. But not when I create a .sh file with the same command. I have also run the command chmod u+x file.sh for permissions along with having a look at the folder permissions. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but over the years, several people have suggested to me not to use `ls` for retrieving file names for this kind of purpose... That I should use `find` instead.

That said, instead of hard-coding the folder path `cd Desktop/NYHETER` directly in your code, if you plan on running **random.sh** directly from within Finder by double clicking it, this following shell script allows the **random.sh** file to be placed in any folder and will randomize the .jpg file names from any folder containing the script and writes the random names to to file in that same folder.

```
#! /bin/bash 

currentDirectory="$(osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set shellScript to container¬ 
 of (get selection as alias) as alias' -e 'set shellScript to POSIX path of shellScript')"

cd "$currentDirectory" || return

find . -name "*.jpg" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 |sort -R |cut -c 3- > ./list.txt
```

Comment: The reasons not to parse the output of `ls` are outlined in [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and further analysed in answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985) on the Unix Stack Exchange. One of the main problems is to do with filenames containing newline characters, which `find` only mitigates if used with the `-print0` option, which separates the results with a NUL byte instead of a linefeed.